# How get mouse position for a custom selection script in Blender 2.8/2.9?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, mouse

I`m trying to make script that selects objects with the same property. Operator "bpy.ops.view3d.select" selects only in the zero position (0,0), and function "event.mouse_x" returns zero mouse position too. Is it possible to solve the problem in blender 2.8/2.9?